# Windows DHCP client only using one DNS server?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp

I have a PC running Windows 7 professional.

It is a DHCP client.

The DHCP server is sending it two DNS servers. This has been verified with packet captures.

However, after running `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` there is only one DNS server configured, the first one.

Why? Is Windows really only extracting a single DNS server from a DHCP reply packet?

Comment: `Is Windows really so stupid that it doesn't know how to extract more than one DNS server from a DHCP reply packet?` - Is Microsoft bashing really necessary?

Comment: If the shoe fits...

Comment: @Hyppy except that it *doesn't* fit in this case, and even a cursory bit of investigation would show this to be the case.

Comment: Are other Windows clients similarly affected?

Comment: @RobM Which is fine and all, except that the quoted part was edited out long ago, while people are still blindly upvoting the now irrelevant comment.

Comment: @RobM Please expound on this "cursory bit of investigation" that you allude to. What is this investigation and how can perform it?

Comment: Please check.  Are you certainly you have not statically configured DNS servers for any of your interfaces?  Your system can be set to use DHCP for obtaining an address, but still be statically configured for DNS.

Comment: Yes I did check that. No static configuration of anything is present on the interface (including DNS).

Comment: Is is strange, but as a course of investigation I would suggest maybe Windows doesn't like one of the DNS addresses it's getting. Do you have a route to both DNS servers? If you use those same addresses manually set up in the client, do they work fine?